# How to adapt a code from amenu to vimscript?

Tags: function, vim

I want to create a function in vimscript which has to read an external document and test it with the text in the buffer.

This is the code which works fine in :amenu (in menu.vim)
`/^\%(.*\<\%(<C-r>=join(readfile('d:\database.txt'),'\\|')<CR>\)\>\)\@!.*$<CR>`

I want to use the same code in a function but don't know how to adapt it.
The above code contains 2 `<CR>`'s which do not work in a function.

**1)** How can I adapt above code to make it work in a vimscript function?

The external document will be inserted using an input dialog

`function! s:CheckWithDocument()`
`if !exists("docinput")`
`let docinput = "Document to match with?"`
`endif`
`let a = inputdialog(docinput)`
`let @/ .....`
`return`
`endfunction`

I call it in amenu: `:call <SID>CheckWithDocument()<CR>`

**2)** How can I insert `'a'` in above vimscript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually harder the other way. They are using the expression register `<C-r>=` to insert some arbitrary vimscript whereas you can just append it to your search string.

```
let @/ = "/^\\%(.*\\<\\%(".join(readfile('d:\database.txt'),'\\\\|')."\\)\\>\\)\\@!.*$"
```

Use the same method to append the `a` variable where you want it.

Comment: Thank you Conner for answering. I inserted your answer in above function and changed the `\` between the double quotes to `\\` but it didn't work. The code is correct but it was not executed as if there was not a <enter> command at the end. When I capture the output (`echo @/`) and insert it in the command-line, push on the enter key, it works fine.

Comment: Oops I changed the `\\` to `\\\\` between double quotes.